# Custom Module Separate Settings for Each User

Tags: 7, forms

I am working on a custom module. I am currently using system_settings_form to enter an API key and it works fine. However, I need users to be able to enter different api keys. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The variables table shouldn't be used for per-user data so you shouldn't use system_settings_form...just a normal form with a normal table defined in `hook_schema()` will do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create module with .install file that would help you to create custom table where you can store individual user API key. I am sharing with you some code to achieve this. It should be something like that. Rest your code will be same you just need to make some minor changes like use `return $form` instead of `return system_settings_form()`. You also need to write `hook_form_submit()` function.

**Module Name:** custom
**1. custom.install**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function custom_install() {
    // Create tables.
    drupal_install_schema('custom_table');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function custom_uninstall() {
    // Drop tables.
    drupal_uninstall_schema('custom_table');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_schema().
 */
function custom_schema() {
  $schema = array();
    $schema['custom_table'] = array(
        'description' => 'Stored user api key',
        'fields' => array(
          'id' => array(
            'type' => 'serial',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique ID.',
          ),
          'api_key' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 256,
            'default' => '',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'description' => 'Store api key',
          ),
        ),  
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

**custom.module**

```
/* Submit hook function for submission form. */
function custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // insert your api key in your custom table using db_insert() function or you can use db_merge() for both insert/update operation.
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for getting me headed in the right direction. I came across this in D7 API i thought I would share it:

As of Drupal 7, a call to drupal_install_schema() is no longer necessary. See http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7: "A module no longer should explicitly install or uninstall its database schema in hook_install() or hook_uninstall()."